# Right way to initialize a variable with null at object creation?

Tags: c#, constructor, null, initialization

I've got a task where I have to learn and understand someone else's code and I'm seeing some constructors that are build like so:

```
string someString;

public myClass(string someString = null){
  this.someString = someString;
}
```

My question is if this is the "best" way of initializing a variable with null?

Because I always did it like this:

```
string someString;

public myClass(){
  someString = null;
}
```

Or like this (even though I can see the problem with this approach):

```
string someString = null;

public myClass(){
}
```

Edit: Changed int to string

Comment: int is a ValueType and can never be null, you need `int?` if it should be nullable

Comment: yes sorry int was a bad example i'll change it.

Comment: As a side note, in both examples of how you would do it, you don't need to explicitly set the `string`, or any other reference type for that matter, to `null`. As long as it's a field or a property (so not a local variable) it will implicitly default to `null` anyway. What you're asking about are [optional arguments/parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the code you are reading and the code you would write, is that the former allows (but not requires) you to set someInt to the desired value on object creation; yours does not.

i can create different versions of MyClass by means of

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5); //someInt initialised as 5
MyClass mySecondClass = new MyClass(10); //someInt initialised as 10
MyClass nullClass = new MyClass(); //someInt initialised as null
```

in your way; the value of someInt is set in the code, and cannot easily be changed

Answer (score 0):

```
public myClass(int? someInt = null)
```

This mean optional parameter constructor, if you pass the variable it will set otherwise it will assign null to variable. e.g:
myClass(10); //will set 10 to someInt
myClass(); //will set null to someInt

```
public myClass(){
  someInt = null;
}
```

This mean in every case it will initialize variable with null.

Comment: You cannot set an integer to null, it's a valuetype